# Lua function return string with C++

Tags: c++, string, function, lua

Is it possible to add a function to Lua via C++ that returns a string?
-edit-
Ok, this code wont work. Any help?

```
int flua_getinput(lua_State *L){
    if(lua_isstring(L,1)){
        cout << lua_tostring(L,1);
        cin >> input;
        cout << "\n";
        lua_pushstring(L,input);
    }else{
        cin >> input;
        cout << "\n";
        lua_pushstring(L,input);
    }
    return 1;
}
Registering Function:

lua_register(L,"getinput",flua_getinput);
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you want more of an answer, you'll have to provide a bit more context: what have you tried, and why doesn't it appear to be working?

Comment: I can't just get a example of how to do it? I'm just trying to learn C++ and Lua. I don't know what to start with.

Comment: Lua error:
lua: [string "init.lua"]:1: attempt to call global 'getinput' (a nil value)

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
int lua_input(lua_State* L) {
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    lua_pushstring(L, input.c_str());
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    lua_State* L=lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_register(L,"input",lua_input);
    luaL_loadstring(L, "for i=1,4 do print('you typed '..input()); end");
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: +1 the OP needs complete code I think. To the OP: If you take this, you **must** also always check every call to loadstring or pcall. And use lua_close at the end.

Comment: @kaizer - you are correct.  I was just trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.html)?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/luaincpp.aspx) shows how you can get a char* from it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use luabind. It automatically detects and deals with std::string so you can simply take a function like, std::string f() and bind it to lua, and it'll automatically be converted to a native lua string when the lua script calls it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error `attempt to call global 'getinput' (a nil value)` then the problem is that the lua_register call is not being hit.  The `getinput` function must be loaded by calling the registration function, or by using `require` if it is in a library.